# Significant time spent in function call

Tags: assembly, fortran

I have a function that is called several times during the course of my code. It takes ~45% of the total time that the code runs (as reported by Intel VTune), but, as the function is computationally expensive, I'm not horribly surprised by this. What I am surprised by, though, is the amount of time VTune tells me I am spending on just the overhead of calling the function (i.e., the time reported right next to the function declaration). The function declaration is as such:

```
subroutine tempFunc(beg, matProp, timestep, matID)
```

The parameters I'm passing to it are simply an `integer`, 100 `real*8` variables, another `real*8`, and an array of 32 `integer`s. As Fortran passes everything by reference, and there are only 4 variables, I don't believe there should be much overhead associated with this call. However, ~15% of the time spent in the function is on said overhead. Looking at the assembly code, all of this time is spent on the following instructions:

```
mov dword ptr [rsp+rax*1], 0xccccccc
sub rax, 0x4
```

I know enough assembly to know that `rsp` is a stack pointer and that `rax` is a 64-bit register. It appears to me that that the first line is moving a pointer to the `rax` register, and that the second line is simply subtracting something from that register. Am I wrong in my understanding? If so, what are these two instructions actually doing? If not, why are these two instructions taking so much time? They seem pretty innocuous.

Comment: You pass the 100 real variables separately in the argument list?

Comment: @VladimirF: No, matProp is an array of 100 real*8's.

Comment: Is it compiler dependent? What is the relative time using `gfortran`, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly.

The first instruction is loading that hex value *into memory* pointed to by a combination of `rsp` and `rax`. The `[...]` is a memory access operation.

The second instruction decrements `rax` by four. It's *this* action that leads me to believe that this *may* well be done in a loop since otherwise, it makes little sense to decrement.

If it's spending 15% on those instructions, that's further support that it's within a loop.

If it *is,* then the loop is filling a chunk of the stack with `0xcccc..cc` values and this may well be expensive.

We'd have to see the entire function to be sure, preferably both the source *and* assembler. You may well have some locals within the function itself which get initialised.

Comment: So basically, it's initializing a bunch of temp variables right at the beginning of the function, then?

Comment: @wolfPack88, can't say for sure without seeing the code but that's my best guess.

Comment: Unfortunately the code is proprietary, so not much more I can give you without getting approval. I do have a compiler option set to initialize temp variables to "an unusual value", though, so I'm going to try rerunning the code without that option and see the results. If it goes away, then you're correct.

Comment: @wolfPack88, that'd be a good start. It can help with debugging to have uninitialised variables sets to a sentinel value like `0xdeadbeef` but doing so will not be advantageous to performance.

Comment: I should probably have looked at the next 2 instructions as well... They're `cmp rax, 0x4` and `jnle 0x14055fe46`, where `0x14055fe46` is the address of the first `mov` command. Indeed, it is a loop assigning random values to stack variables. Thank you for your help.